# Encoding json data as x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python, curl, urlencode

I am trying to POST wih `curl` some data. The source data is in JSON, but I want to post with content-type `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. I am trying to do it like this:

```
curl -X POST $URL --data-urlencode "@$data.json" --header "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

This is data.json:

```
{
  "action"      : "deploy_from_scratch_with_bundle",
  "pusher"      : { "email" : "my@email.com" },
  "ref"         : "refs/heads/master",
  "repo_choice" : "LOCAL"
}
```

But this is not working: `urlparse.parse_qs` (python) is complaining about ValueError.

The received data (before parse_qs) is:

```
%7B%0A%20%20%22action%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%22deploy%5Ffrom%5Fscratch%5Fwith%5Fbundle%22%2C%0A%20%20%22pusher%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%7B%20%22email%22%20%3A%20%22my%40email%2Ecom%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22ref%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22%2C%0A%20%20%22repo%5Fchoice%22%20%3A%20%22LOCAL%22%0A%7D%0A
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: If you perform a bisection search on the received data, can you narrow down which character or sequence specifically is throwing the `ValueError`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use unquote from urllib2 to unquote that data:

```
In [10]: urllib2.unquote("%7B%0A%20%20%22action%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%22deploy%5Ffrom%5Fscratch%5Fwith%5Fbundle%22%2C%0A%20%20%22pusher%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%7B%20%22email%22%20%3A%20%22my%40email%2Ecom%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%22ref%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3A%20%22refs%2Fheads%2Fmaster%22%2C%0A%20%20%22repo%5Fchoice%22%20%3A%20%22LOCAL%22%0A%7D%0A")
Out[10]: '{\n  "action"      : "deploy_from_scratch_with_bundle",\n  "pusher"      : { "email" : "my@email.com" },\n  "ref"         : "refs/heads/master",\n  "repo_choice" : "LOCAL"\n}\n'
```